# UseEffect doesn't seem to work on first render of page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My useEffect doesn't seem to work on first render so the data that I need from the api is not passed to the other components. This means I get an error

```
import "./App.css";
import api from "./api/axiosConfig";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Layout from "./components/Layout";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/home/Home";

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState();

  const getItems = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get("/api/v1/items");

      const itemsList = response.data.splice(10, 20);

      console.log(itemsList);

      setItems(itemsList);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home items={items} />}></Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Not sure what to do. Hvae been struggling for a while on this.

Comment: useEffect runs after the first render, and also your data is async so your code has to expect that it won’t be there at first and handle that gracefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming in your Home component you're mapping over "items", but it's initially undefined while you wait for your data to be fetched.

Since you can't map over something that's undefined, it'll throw an error.

You should be able to fix this by conditionally rendering your list of items in Home, something like:

```
{items ? items.map((item, index) => (
    <p key={index}>{item}</p>
  )) : <p>Loading...</p>}
```

Or you can initialize "items" as an empty array in your App component, like:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to do and initializing the array as empty seems to work. I will also give conditionally rendering the list a try too but the second option seems to work a treat! Thanks so much !

Answer (score 0):

> UseEffect doesn't seem to work on first render of page

With the information we have it's difficult to determine what is the issue, but I think the best thing you could do is to move the *fetching* logic to the `Home` component.